# Create own markers in Google maps Api Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, maps, markers

newcomer here, been searching through google but not finding the help i need. 
Im making a website for outdoor gyms, where I have placed my markers with coords(may have to stash them in mysql) but currently in my code in a markers array.

I want the user to be able to input their adress/county to find the closest outdoor gym/ running track based on their preference. The search should search through the markers and find the closest one in that area.

Until now, i have the map, the markers, the searchfunction is a big obstacle for me atm.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: You should provide some example of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

you could save markers by their coordinates (longitude and latitude) on your db. Then, you could use [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to load googleMap or openstreet map and draw your markers.

This is an useful tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-mean-apps-with-google-maps-part-i. I think it is the good point to start.